# Getting a Attrbute Error for diversipy in Latin HyperCube

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python coding and currently trying to write some code to use for LHS using jupyter notebook.

I've had to manually install and import some of the libraries shown since I had trouble installing git onto my laptop.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import diversipy
import plotly
import polytope
import cvxopt

L = [ 3, 5]
U = [ 10, 10]

a_1 = np.ones((1,2))
b_1 = np.array([10])

np.random.seed(20)

S= 96

X = diversipy.polytope.sample( n_points=S, L=L, U=U, a_1 = a_1, b_1= b_1, thin=2000 )
```

I've managed to set the bounds, constraints, seeds, and sample size accordingly.
However, when I execute the code, I receive an *AttributeError*

> X = diversipy.polytope.sample(n_points=S, L=L, U=U, a_1 = a_1, b_1= b_1, thin=2000)
>
> > **AttributeError:** module **'diversipy'** has no attribute **'polytope'**

Could anyone help to explain this and what I should  to remedy it?

Comment: The simple explanation is that the module that you installed and imported doesn't contain  `polytope`, whether that's a function or class.  The module must have been installed, since the import ran.  I'd double check the docs.  If `polytope` is new feature, check the version.  The fact that you also import a `polytope` is puzzling, but I know nothing of these modules.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I managed to solve it by creating a new conda environment. :)